# Dimension of a elliptic curve as a scheme

Tags: elliptic-curves, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

Let $K$ be complete valuation field, and $R$ be it's ring of integers.
Then,
Elliptic curve is an algebraic variety over field $K$ of dimension $1$.
Elliptic curve can be regarded also as scheme over Spec$R$.

Then, what is the dimension of elliptic curve as a scheme over Spec$R$?(I guess that is $2$・・・)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know any references which take this approach to elliptic curves?

Comment: Afaik dimension is an *absolute* property of a scheme.

Comment: @PtF 'advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves' by J.H.Silverman

Comment: @Mindlack Could you tell me what is afaik dimension property?

Comment: Afaik is internet shorthand for “as far as I know”. I meant that the dimension of a scheme was a property of the “actual underlying topological space” and thus does not depend on the choice of base scheme.

Comment: Then, elliptic curve as a scheme is $1$-dimmensional ?

Comment: @Mindlack but there is a hidden difference in definition in these cases. In one case $E/K$ is $\operatorname{Proj}K[x,y,z]/(f)$ and in the other $E/\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is $\operatorname{Proj}R[x,y,z]/(f)$

Comment: @buoyant why don't you try to find an increasing chain of prime ideals in $R[x,y]/(f(x,y))$ where $f(x,y)$ is a defining equation for $E$.

Comment: @Mummy the turkey: you’re correct, of course. But then one does not speak of “the elliptic curve over $R$ or $K$”: the curve is defined over $K$ and one is interested in the dimension of one of its *models* over $R$.

Comment: @Mindlack yes, that's also a good point. The phrasing in the question is leaving quite a lot to the imagination.